# Android webview make ajax request both get and post

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, webview

I am developing an application that is using webview.
Inside the webview, I am doing a POST request using ajax.
In iOS, it can work as I want.

However, in android, the request turns out to be doing two request: GET and POST.
It makes a routing error on the server side because it should be for POST only.

This is the ajax request code. I don't think there is something wrong with the code since it works well when I open the html page on computer browser and iOS webview.

```
window.onload = function () {
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<%= notif_read_notif_path %>",
   data: {"personal_notice" : {"notice_info_id" : 123}},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
});
```

};

Is there anyone experiencing the similar problem?

Comment: How do you know that android is making two request ? What is the network logging mechanism that you are using?

Comment: Try $.post once, I am not able to reproduce it on my end. See this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for reference.

Comment: @Mr_Hmp Thanks for your comments. I tried $.post, and it does the same thing. Actually I'm developing the server side (the page that is viewed using webview) using Ruby on Rails. I can check the request log and saw that it is making both GET and POST request.